# Why is 'this' a pointer and not a reference?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, this, c++-faq

I was reading the answers to this question [C++ pros and cons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/385297/whats-wrong-with-c-compared-to-other-languages) and got this doubt while reading the comments.

> programmers frequently find it confusing that "this" is a pointer but not a reference. another confusion is why "hello" is not of type std::string but evaluates to a char const* (pointer) (after array to pointer conversion) – Johannes Schaub - litb Dec 22 '08 at 1:56
>
> That only shows that it doesn't use the same conventions as other (later) languages. – le dorfier Dec 22 '08 at 3:35
>
> I'd call the "this" thing a pretty trivial issue though. And oops, thanks for catching a few errors in my examples of undefined behavior. :) Although I don't understand what info about size has to do with anything in the first one. A pointer is simply not allowed to point outside allocated memory – jalf Dec 22 '08 at 4:18
>
> Is this a constant poiner? – yesraaj Dec 22 '08 at 6:35
>
> this can be constant if the method is const int getFoo() const; <- in the scope of getFoo, "this" is constant, and is therefore readonly. This prevents bugs and provides some level of guarantee to the caller that the object won't change. – Doug T. Dec 22 '08 at 16:42
>
> you can't reassign "this". i.e you cannot do "this = &other;", because this is an rvalue. but this is of type T*, not of type T const . i.e it's a non-constant pointer. if you are in a const method, then it's a pointer to const. T const . but the pointer itself is nonconst – Johannes Schaub - litb Dec 22 '08 at 17:53
>
> think of "this" like this: #define this (this_ + 0) where the compiler creates "this_" as a pointer to the object and makes "this" a keyword. you can't assign "this" because (this_ + 0) is an rvalue. of course that's not how it is (there is no such macro), but it can help understand it – Johannes Schaub - litb Dec 22 '08 at 17:55

My question is, why is `this` a pointer a not a reference? Any particular reason for making it a pointer?

---

Some further arguments why `this` being a reference would make sense:

- Consider `Item 1` from `More Effective C++` : use references when it is guaranteed that we have a valid object i.e. not a NULL (my interpretation).
- Furthermore, references are considered safer than pointers (because we can't screw the memory up with a stray pointer).
- Thirdly, the syntax for accessing references (`.`) is a little bit nicer and shorter than accessing pointers (`->` or `(*)`).

Comment: So people can do ugly hacks such as void foo::something() { if (this) stuff(); } }

Comment: @paulm What would this "hack" actually accomplish? Doesn't `this` always evaluate to `true`?

Comment: foo* instance = nullptr; foo->something(); // Now if (this) == false

Comment: @paulm I don't think that's actually valid C++. Invoking methods on a nullptr to an object results in undefined behavior.

Comment: Hmm are you sure about that? I've actually seen it in production code

Comment: @paulm Maybe it works in some cases, but imagine if the method was virutal. How could a v-table lookup be done with no object?

Comment: I guess you'd crash in that case

Comment: @paulm If you've seen it in production code, abandon ship! That is UB.

Comment: I'm just gonna leave this here... (from MFC's afxwin2.inl): `_AFXWIN_INLINE HWND CWnd::GetSafeHwnd() const { return this == NULL ? NULL : m_hWnd; }`

Comment: Related question (not expecting an answer...): why is `this` a keyword, instead of an identifier which is pre-defined within member functions? The parser doesn't need it to be a keyword. Decades ago a co-worker was baffled by a syntax error he was getting, trying to compile some existing working C code. We both looked right at it and couldn't see it. But one of the structs had a field called `this` and he was using a C++ compiler (and, before the days of syntax highlighting).

Answer (score 198, accepted):

When the language was first evolving, in early releases with real users, there were no references, only pointers. References were added when operator overloading was added, as it requires references to work consistently.

One of the uses of `this` is for an object to get a pointer to itself. If it was a reference, we'd have to write `&this`. On the other hand, when we write an assignment operator we have to `return *this`, which would look simpler as `return this`. So if you had a blank slate, you could argue it either way. But C++ evolved gradually in response to feedback from a community of users (like most successful things). The value of backward compatibility totally overwhelms the minor advantages/disadvantages stemming from `this` being a reference or a pointer.

Comment: Well, it is also often useful for an object to get a reference to itself. I'd say that's a more common usage. Anyway, the main reason is like you said, references didn't exist when they created the 'this' pointer.

Comment: If 'this' was a reference, the main use of this would probably be 'this.member' instead of 'this->member', so you would not need the ampersand most of the time.

Comment: i completely agree with your first paragraph. and i think its main use is to get the address of the object. but why would that need a pointer? reference will do equally well and will do better for other cases like "this.foo" and "swap(this, bar)"

Comment: Also, early on C++ used assignment to this in a constructor in place of having an operator new.  That's another important point in its evolution and a reason this is a pointer.

Comment: And, if this were a reference, it would be difficult to overload `operator &` to do anything useful.  There would have to be some special syntax for getting the address of this that wouldn't go through `operator &`.

Comment: Actually, if `this` was a reference, and all other rules remained the same, you **couldn't** get a pointer using `&this`, since you can't apply the `&` operator on references.

Comment: @conio - you might want to check that next time you're near a C++ compiler! :) Something like: `int n = 5; int &r = n; int *p = &r; std::cout << *p;`

Comment: @Omnifarious you could write `&reinterpret_cast<char&>(this);` to get the real address for overloading `operator&` (in fact, this is sort of what `boost::addressof` does).

Comment: Since it doesn't really make any sense for `this` to be null, it seems to me that a reference is really more fitting.

Comment: @PravasiMeet - possibly a confusing use of the & symbol in your question! :)

Comment: @DanielEarwicker: I mean "and" not any operator. difference between return this and return *this.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb that would make it impossible for `operator&` to be constexpr

Answer (score 130):

A little late to the party...  Straight from the horse's mouth, [here's what Bjarne Stroustrup has to say](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#this) (which is essentially repeated in or taken from the "Design and Evolution of C++" book):

> Why is "`this`" not a reference?
>
> Because "this" was introduced into C++ (really into C with Classes) before references were added. Also, I chose "`this`" to follow Simula usage, rather than the (later) Smalltalk use of "self".

Comment: Yeah, self would have been nice for consistency with other languages, oh well.

Comment: `self` could be a keyword that acts like `*this`.

Comment: `#define self *this`

Comment: `#define self (*this)`

Answer (score 10):

In addition to the other answers, since [Deducing this](https://wg21.link/p0847) is [in C++23](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/pull/5002), it will be possible to have a reference to the object for which a member function is called (instead of `this` pointer):

```cpp
struct Foo {
  void bar(this Foo& self) {
    // self is a reference to Foo
  }
};

int main() {
  Foo foo;
  foo.bar();
}
```

Comment: Any language where you can write something like `this Self&& self` has some inherent problems... It seems that with all the new C++ revisions, they are adding more and more things that just fix problems with the language itself instead of adding functionality. `forward_like`, `declval`, `to_address`, `launder`, `start_lifetime_as`, `enable_if`, `void_t`, `destroying_delete_t`, `reference_wrapper`, `move_only_function`, `bind_front/back`, etc etc

Comment: What those things are adding is more fine grained control for applications when it really matters, and safer/easier ways to complete tasks that are a pain otherwise. C++ is first and foremost a systems language. Total control of everything is an absolute requirement. So naturally it will have a lot of dirty interfaces because systems are dirty places.