# autoreferencing this class to use in another for C++

Tags: java, c++, this

in java we can do this:

```
public class A{

    public static void main(String...str){
        B b  = new B();
        b.doSomething(this);   //How I do this in c++ ? the this self reference
    }
}


public class B{
    public void doSomething(A a){
        //Importat stuff happen here
     }
}
```

How can I do the same but in c++, I mean the self reference of A to use the method in B ?

Comment: Are you sure that captures your question? `this` is a keyword in C and it still does exactly that.

Comment: Your code will not compile. You cannot use `this` from a static context.

Comment: Yes is correct I cannot use this in static context, just suppose that is not static

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in a static method there is no `this` parameter. Anyway, assuming that main() is not static here is how you can do it in C++

```
class A {
public:
   void f() { 
      B* b = new B();  
      b->doSomething(this);
   }

   void g() { 
      // ...
   };
};


class B {
public:
   void doSomething(A* a) {
       // You can now access members of a by using the -> operator:
       a->g();
   }
};
```

In C++ `this` is a pointer to the "current" Object. Thus if you define `doSomething()` as taking a pointer to A (that is: `doSomething(A* a)`), then you will be able to receive the `this` of `A`. The -> operator will give you access to the members of the `a` parameter, as follows: `a->g()`.

Alternatively you can pass `*this` and define `doSomething()` to take a reference to `A` (that is: `doSomething(A& a)`):

```
class A {
public:
   void f() { 
      B* b = new B();  
      b->doSomething(*this);
   }

   void g() { 
      // ...
   };
};


class B {
public:
   void doSomething(A& a) {
       // You can now access members of a by using the . operator:
       a.g();
   }
};
```

To access members of a reference you need to use the `.` (dot) operator: `a.g()`.

Answer (score 1):

`this` is a keyword in C++ *pointing* to the current object. Perhaps you want `*this` which is a reference to the current object.

I'd say that this is an anachronism; references are more common than pointers in most modern C++ code and everything would work quite fine if `this` were defined to be a reference.

But the inconvenience is small.

Comment: @Potatocorn: Unrelated but see this question on why `this` is a pointer and not a reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645994/why-this-is-a-pointer-and-not-a-reference

Answer (score 1):

C++ has `this` key word. But it is pointer and not a reference. In your case you need to change the signature of doSomething in class B to `doSomething(A* pA)` and use it like `b.doSomething(this);`

Answer (score 0):

Java is a "modern" compiler. Modules are correctly compiled, including their cross-references. C++ is an "old" compiler, smart enough to do everything in a single pass over the source code. However, this implies that it will let you reference A from B, and even B from A, provided that you only use pointers to them. Actually, when C++ compiles A it does not know that you there is a B class. Okay, we can fix this by preceding the declaration of A with:

```
class B;
```

Which equals to say to the compiler: okay, there is a B class somewhere else. Fantastic. Now you can put parameters of the kind "B* b", because a pointer is just a pointer (4 bytes in 32bits architectures...). However, you won't be able to compile something like, say, a parameter-by-value "B b", because among other things, the compiler needs to know the size of the class B, as it hasn't even compiled it yet.

There are other considerations about your code, specially about passing *this*, (*this* is a pointer), but those aspects have been answered yet.