# Would making 'this' a reference rather than a pointer be better in retrospect?

Tags: c++, language-design

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why ‘this’ is a pointer and not a reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645994/why-this-is-a-pointer-and-not-a-reference)

Is there any reason for `this` in C++ to be a pointer rather than a reference other than historical language decision?  It feels a tad strange given that e.g. copy constructor or assignment operators both accept *reference* to "`that`", not a pointer.

[*I honestly couldn't find this question, though it does feel like a possible duplicate*]

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a dupe but I'm having similar trouble finding it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why 'this' is a pointer and not a reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645994/why-this-is-a-pointer-and-not-a-reference) - found via [google](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+c%2B%2B+why+is+this+not+a+reference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[References didn't exist](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#this) in the language when `this` was created.

Comment: If that's indeed so, it's sure *the* answer.

Comment: Trying to find a source to cite...

Comment: There we go, straight from the horse's mouth :)

Answer (score 6):

From Bjarne Stroustrup's "The Design and Evolution of C++", Addison-Wesley, 1994, pp 39-40:

> Sometimes, people ask why `this` is a pointer rather than a reference and why it is called `this` rather than `self`. When `this` was introduced into C with Classes, the language didn't have references, and C++ borrows its terminology from Simula rather than Smalltalk.

Comment: Also here: http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#this