# Why is this a pointer

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why 'this' is a pointer and not a reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645994/why-this-is-a-pointer-and-not-a-reference)

Why is `this` a pointer, rather rhan reference?  Can it ever be `NULL`?

Comment: It can be null. Imagine the case when a *non-virtual* method is invoked upon ... well, NULL :-) This might be well into the realm of C++ UB, but I've seen it occur before.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [Why 'this' is a pointer and not a reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645994/why-this-is-a-pointer-and-not-a-reference) and a handful of other questions.

Comment: @pst:  Yes, that would be well into the realm of undefined behavior.

Comment: For one thing, it allows for `delete this;`

Comment: @meagar:  If it were a reference, you could `delete &this;`.

Comment: @James Clearly the language was designed with `this` as a pointer solely to save one keystroke. Who wants to have to type `&this` *every time*?

Comment: @James McNellis - delete &this; might be tricky, if the class has overload for the operator &.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why is "`this`" not a reference?

See Bjarne's answer [here](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#this)

> Because "this" was introduced into C++ (really into C with Classes) before references were added. Also, I chose "`this`" to follow Simula usage, rather than the (later) Smalltalk use of "self".

Answer (score 2):

> > Why is `this` a pointer?

Because it is, and it is just the way the programming language was designed. (I think it is also because it was left over from C, but I am not sure).

> > rather than a reference?

If you need a this reference, use `*this`.

> > Can it never be `NULL`?

...no. How could it be?

Comment: it's a reasonable question - if it can never be null or reassigned why isn't it a reference?

Comment: why can't it be a pointer? There is no advantage of it being either because the conversion between involves one character (* or &).

Comment: @AlexanderRafferty Because that the C++ way is passing references.