# Why use this->ObjectName instead of this.ObjectName in c++

Tags: java, c++

Hello World, I have been wondering why in c++ we use the this->*ObjectName* instead of this.*ObjectName* when referring to an object in c++. This is a simple syntax using the this->*ObjectName* :

```
     int x = 34;
     void take(int x) {
      this->x = x;
     }
```

But in other programming languages like java, we use :

```
     int x = 34;
     void take(int x) {
      this.x = x;
     }
```

So what am asking is why does the **this** statement in c++ differ from the **this** statement in java

Comment: Because C++ is not Java and `this` is a pointer.

Comment: It's not unreasonable to imagine that different languages have different syntax.  In c++, `->` dereferences a pointer + accesses a property, where `.` just accesses a property.

Comment: From Stroustrup, *The C++ Programming Language, Fourth Edition*, page 465, "... the keyword *this* is a pointer to the object for which the function was invoked."

Comment: To the close voters, this is definitely not "primarily opinion based".

Comment: @juan I voted to close as opinion based because of the *why doesn't this work like it does in Java?* question. But maybe it's better to mark it as a dupe of [this](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F645994%2Fwhy-this-is-a-pointer-and-not-a-reference&ei=lfR0U9ibCsj_oQSj8YGwCQ&usg=AFQjCNF_DHE_cHuvE86Ewd9ylCGme1c1rg&sig2=0kGt8NaObM2fHi0MnpS2MA&bvm=bv.66699033,d.cGU)?

Comment: Thanks guy, I am anyway just a beginner in c++, i should have put that in mupy question but am a pro in java and thanks anyway I just learnt about the c++ arrow member selection operator than I wanted to know why it was so different from java but thanks anyway.

Comment: @user3526881: How can you be a "pro" in Java without having written native JNI code in C or in C++, where you usually deal with pointers all the time?

Comment: @Praetorian I think the duplicate is a better close reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This only applies to pointers. Expressions of class/struct type (references inclusive) use the more familiar dot notation:

```
class Whatever {
 public:
  int x;
  void take(int n);
};

class T {
  public:
   int x;
};

void Whatever::take(int n) {
  T t;
  T *pt = &t; // pointer
  T &tr = t;  // reference is basically just an alias

  pt->x   = n;
  (*pt).x = n; // can dereference a pointer, then use like a reference
  tr.x    = n;

  // Same for this.
  this->x   = n;
  (*this).x = n;
}
```

What may seem odd to you is that `this` is a pointer in C++ as opposed to a reference.

See also: **[Why 'this' is a pointer and not a reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645994/why-this-is-a-pointer-and-not-a-reference)** (Stroustrup introduces `this` before he created references in the language.)

Comment: It's not so much "references" as it is "values of class type". Being a reference is a property of a variable, not of an expression. You can say `foo().x += 1`, for example...

Comment: Good point, clarification added. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In `Java/C#`, almost everything is of reference type (except the primitive ones, struct in c# etc.). But in C++, both `value` and `reference` semantics are used.  Use

```
Myclass{ 
 public: void foo(){} 
};

Myclass ob; //as value
ob.foo();
```

and

```
Myclass * ob; //as pointer
ob->foo();
```

Note: except pointer, there is another way for reference usage in `C++`, which is the **reference** itself, but in c++, reference is used as an alias for an object, so it is like the value type (like Java/C#).

```
 Myclass ob; //as value
 Myclass& ref=ob; // reference to ob
 ref.foo();
```

Comment: `struct`s and primitive types are [value types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) in C#.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you have pointers. With pointers `->` is used. With references/objects `.` is used.

Comment: Pointers are objects, too...

Comment: That's just how C++ works. Lots of things are objects.

Comment: @KerrekSB: please elaborate, what properties of an object do they have? IMHO they are more like primitives (int)

Comment: `int`s are objects, too! Objects are things that are stored in memory (see 1.8/1). There's generally not so much difference between built-in and user-defined types, and that's by design. Same treatment for everyone.