# Why this->attribute and not this.attribute in this case (C++ OOP)?

Tags: c++, oop

I'm learning C++ OOP. I understand functions and pointers (or at least I think so), but now I'm reading an example of a C++ class called "Student" and I found the following:

```
    void Student::modify_mark(double mark)
    {
      this->mark = mark;
    }
```

I know that this->mark is equivalent to (*this).mark, but I really don't get why we need a pointer in this case. Why not this.mark? We want to modify the mark of the student, right?

Comment: Because this is always a pointer. That's how the language is. (It does't require copies of the object, is more flexible than a reference, etc.etc.)

Comment: Yep but if it's a pointer by itself why do you have to call it as a pointer? I mean, if "this" is a pointer, then "*this" is a pointer to the pointer. My mind is about to blow.

Comment: No, `*this` is the thing it points to. You are confusing it with `&this`, which would be a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: OK now I understand, thank you

Comment: @deviantfan - What flexibility is gained through `this` being a pointer vs. a reference?  Since it's defined as either `*const` or `const*const` I can't think of one.  It can't ever be `nullptr` in any context that doesn't cause UB...

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is: because.

In C++, `this` is a pointer. It has always been a pointer. It is what it is. Bears bear, bees bee, Spock beams up, and in C++ `this` is a pointer.

Could it have been a reference instead? Sure, I can't immediately see any technical reason why not. But, when C++ was a dream in Stroustrup's mind, he dreamed up `this` to be a pointer. If, by sheer luck, you ever run into him, you might want to ask him this question. You might get a fascinating answer, if so please share it with us, when that happens.

But since `this` was a pointer from the beginning, forever a pointer it shall be, until the heat death of the universe.

Comment: For further reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/645994/why-this-is-a-pointer-and-not-a-reference

Comment: Great answer. Thank you, I thought that "this" as non-pointer element could also exist

Comment: If @Jose runs into Mr. Stroustrup I hope they both come out OK. Hate to see people injured in pointless collisions.

Answer (score 0):

Because `this` is a pointer.

As said in CPP reference:

> The keyword this is a prvalue expression whose value is the address of
>   the object, on which the member function is being called. It can
>   appear in the following contexts: 1) Within the body of any non-static
>   member function, including member initializer list 2) within the
>   declaration of a non-static member function anywhere after the
>   (optional) cv-qualifier sequence, including dynamic exception
>   specification(deprecated), noexcept specification(C++11), and the
>   trailing return type(since C++11) 3) within default member initializer
>   (since C++11)
>
> The type of this in a member function of class X is X* (pointer to X).
>   If the member function is cv-qualified, the type of this is cv X*
>   (pointer to identically cv-qualified X). Since constructors and
>   destructors cannot be cv-qualified, the type of this in them is always
>   X*, even when constructing or destroying a const object.
>
> When a non-static class member is used in any of the contexts where
>   the this keyword is allowed (non-static member function bodies, member
>   initializer lists, default member initializers), the implicit this->
>   is automatically added before the name, resulting in a member access
>   expression (which, if the member is a virtual member function, results
>   in a virtual function call).
>
> In class templates, this is a dependent expression, and explicit
>   this-> may be used to force another expression to become dependent.
>
> It is possible to execute delete this;, if the program can guarantee
>   that the object was allocated by new, however, this renders every
>   pointer to the deallocated object invalid, including the this pointer
>   itself: after delete this; returns, such member function cannot refer
>   to a member of a class (since this involves an implicit dereference of
>   this) and no other member function may be called. This is used, for
>   example, in the member function of the control block of
>   std::shared_ptr responsible for decrementing the reference count, when
>   the last reference to the managed object goes out of scope.

Comment: OK but then shouldn't "*this" be a pointer to the pointer, if this is a pointer by itself?

Comment: No. You're confused about what `*` means.

Answer (score -1):

In C++ the `this` reserved keyword, is a pointer to the current class instance, therefore since it is a pointer, you must use `->`