# I have come across some C++ code.Why we have to use *this in block instead of this?

Tags: c++, this, this-pointer

I have the following code, and I'm wondering why it uses `*this` instead of `this`.

```
class Quotation
{
protected:
    int value;
    char* type;
public:
    virtual Quotation* clone()=0;

    char * getType()
    {
        return type;
    }

    int getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }
};


class bikeQuotation : public Quotation
{
public:
    bikeQuotation(int number)
    {
        value=number;
        type="BIKE";
    }

    Quotation * clone()
    {
        return new bikeQuotation(*this);  // <-- Here!
    }
};
```

Comment: Because `this` is a pointer, but copy constructor accepts const reference to an INSTANCE (`*this`)

Comment: Totally unrelated to your query, but very related to the question, please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645994/why-this-is-a-pointer-and-not-a-reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` is a *pointer* to the object. The copy constructor requires a *reference* to the object. The way you convert a pointer to a reference is with the dereferencing `*` operator.