# Why do you use -> to access struct member variables even if you haven't explicitly defined the struct as a pointer?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, struct, member

I have a struct that I never explicitly defined as a pointer. But when I try to access its member variables with a `.` instead of `->`, I get an error, and `->` seems to be the only correct option.

As far as I understand, you only use `->` to dereference a pointer to a class and access its members. In the code below, `Employee` is not a pointer, but if I use `.`, I get an error. Why is that so?

```
struct Employee {
  public:
    int getAge(){ return this.age; }
    void setAge(int age){ this.age = age; }
  private:
    int age{18};
};

int main() {
  Employee emp;
  emp.setAge(55);
  std::cout << emp.getAge() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: `this` is a pointer of type `Employee*`.

Comment: `setAge(string age)` should be `setAge(int age)`.

Comment: Closely related: [Why is 'this' a pointer and not a reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645994/why-is-this-a-pointer-and-not-a-reference)

Answer (score 3):

In C++, `this` is a pointer to the current object rather than a reference to it. As a result, even though you’ve never declared any pointers, if you use `this` you’ll need to use pointer syntax.

(The reason `this` is a pointer and not a reference is historical. The `this` keyword was added to the language before references were.)

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you have to use the `->` operator is because `this` is a pointer. It is a special kind of pointer. The `this` pointer is a pointer that points to an object of which the member function was called.  `This` is used to retrieve an object. The `this` pointer in your example is retrieving the object `age`. The `this` pointer is also an r-value. Specifically a [prvalue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues). Here's the [reference](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/class.this#1) as well. Thanks to @user4581301 for contributing to this as well.

For example using your example and tweaking a few things:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Employee {
public:
 // You want to use pointer syntax for the this pointer. By using the arrow operator.
    int getAge() { return this->age; }
    void setAge(int age) { this->age = age; } //Then changing setAge to an int rather than a string.
private:
    int age{ 18 };
}; // Don't forget the semicolon. 

int main() {
    Employee emp;
    emp.setAge(55);
    std::cout << emp.getAge() << '\n';
}
```