# use a pointer to the current object - C++

Tags: c++, class, object, pointers, this

just wondering how to use (pass or return) a pointer to the current object in c++?

in my case I have a map of nodes, and I want to assign a node a child, and in doing so have the current node be added as a parent to the child

below is what I have right now

```
void node::assign_child(node* child)
{
   children.push_back(child);
   child->parents.push_back(*this???);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `this` itself is a pointer, named as "the this pointer".

About why is it a pointer, [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/645994/why-is-this-a-pointer-and-not-a-reference) might be helpful.

Or just look at what the C++17 Standard says.
§12.2.2.1 **The this pointer** stands:

> the keyword `this` is a prvalue expression whose value
> is the address of the object for which the function is called. The type of this in a member function of a class
> `X` is `X*`.

Answer (score 2):

Very close, but `this` is itself a pointer. You don't want to dereference `this` or else you'll just get a value.

```
child->parents.push_back(this);
```